# Android - Package files folder will be deleted while upgrading an app in Google PlayMarket?

Tags: java, android

I had developed Android Application which has **Login Authentication Page.** When the user logs in with valid data, the details are stored in **Shared Preferences** (shared_prefs folder in `data/data/<App_PackageName>/<shared_prefs> folder` as `SharedPreferences.xml` file). So when the user minimizes and maximizes the App, the Shared Preferences is working fine. I recently upgraded the App in the market with updated version Name and Version Code. The users gets the notification and upgrading the App from the market. While launching upgraded version, the app is displaying the Login Auth Page again. I thought that shared Preferences are deleted while upgrading the app, so i changed the storing the details from `Prferences.xml to .txt file.` The text file is storing in `data/data/<App_PackageName>/<files>` folder. Here my questions are:

```
1.The `files` folder and `shared_prefs` folder are stored in cache memory?
2. Whether cache will be cleared while upgrading the app from the market?
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you want to do? Clear the settings of the previous version or keep those settings? If you want to clear the previous settings then write the version of your app into `SharedPreferences` then write code which checks to see if it's a new version and clear the previous data.

Comment: My question is very clear. I dont want to clear the previous data. If the data is already present in the private Application Storage, just navigate to HOMEPAGE instead of LOGIN PAGE.

Comment: No your question wasn't very clear. Your answer to my comment/question was, however. This is a simple case of saving `Boolean` such as `first_run` to `SharedPreferences` and checking it each time your launcher `Activity` starts. If `first_run` doesn't exist then go through the login process...if it does exist and it is `false` then go to the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither are stored in the cache memory, the correct term is private application storage. Application database goes there too. All these will be kept intact when you upgrade the application.

There will be very little use of the application storage if it got erased with every application update right? Imagine yourself having to pass the same troublesome level of a game after each upgrade...

By the way there is a warning that pops out when you are about to upgrade an application, saying explicitly that `your application data will be kept intact`.

Comment: so, what i have done is shared preferences are called only when app is onPause(). when upgrading the app we have to call onStop() method and onRestore() method. Right?

Comment: @avadhani I don't quite get you. Updating the application is quite an automatic process. On the other hand the `sharedPreferences` is just data stored in a place where it can be easily accessed. How do you call data? Basically when updating you do not need to do anything to preserve your `SharedPreferences` just continue using them as you always did.

Comment: @avadhani Btw if you are so unsure of what will happen: this is the same as having the application already installed on the phone and running it from the IDE once more (i.e. overwriting older version with newer). Just observe what happens in this case and you can be pretty sure this will happen when updating from the market.

Comment: yes, while running it from the IDE which is already installed in the phone, there is no problem with the app. But upgrading from the market the app is displaying the Login Page. I really cant understand what is happening while app upgradation from the market :(

Answer (score 1):

Preferences aren't automatically deleted when you simply update the app. Either the user is uninstalling first, or they are using a 3rd party market alternative which is uninstalling or deleting your preferences.

Or you have some code in your app that determines the version of the app is newer than the version was the last time your app was run, and then clears your settings manually.

Comment: When long click the HOME Button in the Android device, the task manager button with currently running apps will show up. Click TASK MANAGER button and END the Android app. In this case the app is asking for login. Actually what will happen while clicking the END from TASK MANAGER button in Android